# How to define multiple threads in MultiItemResource Reader?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-batch

I am using `MultiResourceItemReader` class of Spring Batch. Which uses `FlatFileReader` bean as delegate.My files contains XML requests, my batch reading requestes from files hit its on to URL and writing response to corresponding output files. I want to define one thread for each file processing to decrease execution time. In my current requirement I have four input files , I want to define four thread to read ,process and write files. I tried with simpleTaskExecuter with

```
task-executor="simpleTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="20"
```

But after using this `flatfileReader` is throwing `Exception`. 
I am beginner, please suggest me how to implement this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to go here.  However, the easiest way would be to partition by file using the `MultiResourcePartitioner`.  That in combination with the `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` will give you reliable parallel processing of your input files.  You can read more about partitioning in section 7.4 of our documentation here:  http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/scalability.html